# Add multitouch to simple tapping game in Flash/AIR and AS3

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, air, adobe

I have a simple game that I made in Flash CS5.5 which involves the user simply tapping on an object and getting points. Is there anyway I can implement multi-touch to the game without having to do everything again so that the user can touch different objects with different fingers?

Answer (score 2):

have you tried setting your app to multitouch mode with:

```
Multitouch.inputMode=MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT;
```

changing your `MouseEvent.CLICK` event listeners to `TouchEvent.TOUCH_TAP`

That should get you in the right direction... Do you have a specific implementation problem?